# Inserting into an atomic index rewrite structure in a single command

Tags: redis

I'm creating a rewrite lookup structure to map IDs from a string namespace to a numeric index. The reason I'm doing this is that the string IDs are large (hundreds of bytes), there are millions of them, and they are used many different objects within Redis. Mapping the complex string IDs to a more succinct namespace will help fit into resident memory design considerations.

One way to achieve the above is to insert into some structure, and receive back an auto incremented integer if the key to insert does not exist. If it does exist, simply like to receive back the integer previously associated.

One non-atomic way to express the above, via Python, is the following:

```
def get_or_set(d, item):
    if item not in d:
        d[item] = len(d)
    return d[item]
```

Insert operations will be in parallel, so a solution would need to be atomic.

I can see ways to perform the above in Redis with multiple commands within a transaction. What I'm wondering is if there is a single command?

A single command is not a strict requirement, but a pleasant one. The above is not an uncommon task, so I thought that Redis may have added direct support -- I'm still learning the suite of commands and easily may have overlooked something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably several ways to do what you want, so I'll explain one of the simpler ones. There is no single Redis command to all of this, but you can assemble the ones that are available to solve this neatly.

We'll use a single Redis Hash to store all of the data. The Hash, stored in the key called "data", will have a field for each of your string ids with its value being the numeric id. A single additional field in the Hash, called "current_id" assuming this isn't one of the string ids, will store the last numeric id.

Without caring about atomicity, you'd do this (`r` is your connection to Redis):

```
def get_or_set(item):
    kid = r.hget('data', item)
    if kid is None:
        kid = r.hincrby('current_id', 1)
        r.hset('data', item, kid)
    return kid
```

To add atomicity, you'll want to migrate that to a Lua script. The script will be run atomically server-side so that takes care of any possible race conditions.

```
SCRIPT = """
    local kid = redis.call('HGET', KEYS[1], ARGV[1])
    if not kid then
      kid = redis.call('HINCRBY', KEYS[1], 'current_id', 1)
      redis.call('HSET', KEYS[1], ARGV[1], kid)
    end
    return kid
"""

SHA = r.script_load(script)

def get_or_set(item):
    return r.evalsha(SHA, 1, 'data', item)
```

Comment: Thank you! I was just starting down the route of Lua :)

Comment: I highly recommend that route ;)